# Download of file from App on Kubernetes 0KB

Tags: kubernetes, containers

Is there a way to set a longer time out in Kubernetes, I'm not sure where this setting would be but I am trying to download a file and after around 5 mins it seems to timeout and the file ends up 0kb and errors when I try to open it.

I realised there probably isnt enough information here to go off so please let me know what else I can provide to assist in helping me.

Thanks

Nav

Comment: Hello Nav, could you give more context? That timeout could be set in many things. Are you using an app/tool deployed in some pod to download this file? or Are you trying to get a file from a pod to your local machine? I didn't get it. If you can provide more details and names, it would be helpful.

Comment: Hi so I am trying to download from pod to local system an Excel file. I have tried to run a tests in terms of size of data and noticed that 40K records downloads fine and 84K seams to time out . Around 5 mins or under works, beyond 5 mins or longer times out and results in a 0kb file size. Is there a way to increase this time out window?

Comment: oh I see, as far as I know, there is no way - yet - to set a timeout but you can do some workaround like `kubectl exec -i [pod name] -c [container name] -- bash -c "cat [path to file]" > [output file]` -- This isn't the best way but it works.
re: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60140

Comment: I think I would like to provide some more context. The link you shared refers to cp fail, I am not using kubectl cp for this. Sorry I should have made this clear. The file is being downloaded via app UI and times out. < 5 mins seems to work, > 5mins fails, I had exec into the container changed to something like the temp dir and ran a watch ls -lh, triggered the download in the UI and checking to see if the file size grows with time. Also checking dev tools to see times and this eventually ends with a 0kb file > 5mins. This leads me to believe I need to increase a time out setting somewhere?

Comment: Check if the pod restarts. If possible please include pod manifest to your question. It's possible pod's healthcheck is failing due to oversaturated bandwidth. Even if that's not the case you should store large files in persistent volumes, and configure your app to download files from the volume, not directly from the pod.

Comment: So data is pulled from Elastic Search into the app ui, which is hosted on docker containers in k8s. I had forgot to mention that the time out issue being faced is different in different environments. In UAT we can see 12 min time out and live it seems to be 5 mins. I am yet to look at the pod manifest.

Comment: Please include both production and UAT pod manifests (if possible of course, with critical info obfuscated).